# Remove index column from DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched a lot about this topic of how to remove the index column of the datframe when exporting the dataframe to csv file. I found many solutions and tricks but none of them worked with me.
In the csv output I got 0 (the column index) at the first row of the CSV output.
Can you guide me of fixing such a problem?!!

Comment: Have you tried `df.to_csv(index=False)`?

Comment: are you using `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before doing `df.to_csv(index=False)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried both and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using pandas?
If so, you can use the .to_csv method with the argument index=False to remove index:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

or header=False to remove column names:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my first try and this removes the row's index not the column index.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your support.

Comment: Does this print the results into terminal?

Comment: @alper it doesn't. It only creates a csv file. If you want to print something you have to say it to print whatever you want to print.

Comment: Can I redirect it to the terminal in paralel ? or should I do `cat output.csv'` inside the python script?